# Наследование перегруженных операций

Tags: c++

Передаются ли классам наследникам операции перегруженные в базовом классе?

Comment: операции перегружены у типа, т.е. нет, не передаются.

Comment: а запись using TOutputPin::operator =; где  TOutputPin базовый класс?

Comment: Приведите пример кода.

Comment: В производном классе необходимо явно определять свои конструкторы, деструкторы и перегруженные операторы присваивания  из-за  того,  что  они  не  наследуются  от  базового  класса. Но  их  можно вызвать явным образом при определении конструктора, деструктора или перегрузки оператора присваивания производного класса, например таким образом (для конструктора): `Конструктор_Производного_Класса (/*параметры*/)  :  Конструктор_Базового_Класса ( /*параметры*/) { }`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb ну во нашел похожее

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882186/trouble-with-inheritance-of-operator-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял из вопроса и комментариев вас интересует будет ли в классе наследнике доступен `operator=()` из базового класса. Нет он доступен не будет. Причина в том, что компилятор неявно создает оператор копирующего присваивания, который скрывает все унаследованные перегрузки `operator=()`. Для решения этой проблемы можно воспользоваться `using`-ом:

```
struct A{
    int i;
    void operator =(int value){
        i = value;
    }
};

struct B : A{
    using A::operator =;
};
```

С другими операторами проблем быть не должно.

Comment: т.е. написав так я, в классе наследнике, говорю использовать операторы родительского класса?

что я и искал.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял из вопроса, вас интересует, передаются ли наследникам *overloaded* функции (т.е. имеющие несколько сигнатур). Они передаются в том случае, если используется `public` наследование (как и не перегруженные функции):

```
struct Base
{
    int foo(int a);
    int foo(double a);
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
   // Наследует int foo(int a);
   // Наследует int foo(double a);
};
```

Но это правило не распространяется на конструкторы, деструкторы и операторы присвоения. Они должны быть определены явно, или (начиная с С++11) явно унаследованы - в противном случае компилятор автоматически сгенерирует их, перекрыв родительские. С этим связан вопрос, на который вы дали ссылку в комментарии.